# Equivalent ORM Query in Laravel

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

Following is my query:

```
select nonrem_id as RefID  , (SELECT group_concat(concat(nonremu_updated_date, ' - ',name,' - ',ttu.nonremu_updates) SEPARATOR ',') FROM `fanda_bank_nonremit_update` as ttu left join fanda_mst_users on login_id = nonremu_createdby WHERE ttu.nonremu_cid = fanda_bank_acc_nonremitted.nonrem_id order by ttu.nonremu_id asc ) as Comments from `fanda_bank_acc_nonremitted` left join `fanda_mst_users` on `login_id` = `nonrem_created_by` where `nonrem_gl_date` >= 2017-02-01 and `nonrem_gl_date` <= 2017-05-11 and `nonrem_country` = BE
```

How do I write this query in Laravel Eloquent ORM. I have tried using Query builder, but I wanna know how to write this query in pure ORM.

P.S: I should not use DB::raw() anywhere.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you'll need `DB::raw()` to build a select statement like that.

EDIT:

If you don't care about using `DB::raw()` on your select, then try something like this on your select:

```
Model::select('nonrem_id as RefID',DB::raw('(SELECT group_concat(concat(nonremu_updated_date, ' - ',name,' - ',ttu.nonremu_updates) SEPARATOR ',') FROM `fanda_bank_nonremit_update` as ttu left join fanda_mst_users on login_id = nonremu_createdby WHERE ttu.nonremu_cid = fanda_bank_acc_nonremitted.nonrem_id order by ttu.nonremu_id asc ) as Comments'))
```

If you are using strict mode it will throw a `QueryException` cause you are ordering your first query by a non selected field , to avoid this query exception configure your db connection to allow this kind of order by. You can do it on the file: `config/database.php` by adding this two parameters to your actual connection within your 'connections' array:

```
  'strict' => true,
  'modes' => ['STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
              'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
              'NO_ZERO_DATE',
              'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
              'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
              'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'],
```

Comment: Thanks @aaron0207 . Is it possible to write the query using selectRaw(). If so then how do I write the above query where there is a select within select.